# Can any one tell me these gesture name's in iOS . Any good example code will be helpful

Tags: ios, objective-c

kindly tell me which gesture they are using in my given screen shoot. If there is any example code or similar to this example then please tell me. I search over google with more than 15 different queries but did find any example like this .

As you can see they are not using a full page swipe but half.

Please check these two screen shoots

[image: http://i58.tinypic.com/zna0zc.png]

[image: http://i61.tinypic.com/28k4o7q.png]

Thanks

Comment: It's a customized view. And probably they used a customized UIButton or UITapGesture. If it like swipe, it can be UIPanGesture.

Comment: Hey Android WE use UITapGesture for it ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use simple view animation for the same.

```
-(IBAction)tabPressed:(id)sender
   {
     if([sender isSelected])
     {
             sender.selected=NO;
             [UIView beginAnimations:@"animation" context:NULL];
                [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5];
               //set here frame to go down
                [UIView commitAnimations];
    }
    else
    {
    sender.selected=YES;
             [UIView beginAnimations:@"animation" context:NULL];
                [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5];
               //set here frame to go up
                [UIView commitAnimations];
    }
  }
```

Comment: Do you have any sample working project ? Then please share with me

Comment: I don't. But use this code and assign tabPressed: method to one button which will be placed on Tips text. According to that button selection set the views frame.origin.y to go view up and down. It work for you.

Comment: When i press button then which view will appear ? Can i assign that view in tab pressed and thats ok to fix frame.origin.y.

Comment: Yes You have to Assign IBOutlet to view which you have to do up and down

Answer (score 0):

Seems like there's a low-level work with gestures based on `touchesBegan:` and `touchesMoved:` methods.

Answer (score 0):

Just Create A UITapGesture like this

```
   UITapGestureRecognizer  *tapGestureRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleTapFrom:)];
```

And Do Something here For Hide According You ...

```
 - (void) handleTapFrom: (UITapGestureRecognizer *)recognizer
   {
     //Code to handle the gesture
  }
```

Comment: In - (void) handleTapFrom: (UITapGestureRecognizer *)recognizer..... Method you need to wright whatever you want to do on That tap...

Comment: when this function will be call ?   UITapGestureRecognizer  *tapGestureRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleTapFrom:)];

Comment: When you tap, then this method will call (handleTapFrom:)

Answer (score 0):

Could be everything:

- a simple button that trigger a slide up animation
- if you can drag it and it stays attached to the finger is a pan Gesture recognizer
- if the movement is a swipe, it is a swipe gesture recognizer